# how to edit every item in a list and create a new one in dart

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

What is the quickiest method in dart to accomplish the following?

From This:

`List<String> myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];`

To This:

`List<String> myNewList = ['text1Atext2', 'text1Btext2', 'text1Ctext2', 'text1Dtext2'];`

so just appending some string at te beginning and some other at the end of every item

EDIT sorry I found it

`var myNewList = myList.map((x) => 'text1' + x + 'text2').toList;`

Comment: `var myNewList = [for (var s in myList) 'text1${s}text2'];`

Answer (score 0):

yourlist.foreach((item){}); is another way to process the list and do changes on every items